# Prepositions used with "inquire"

Tags: prepositions

May one use *inquire with* instead of the somewhat overly official and potentially archaic *inquire of*?

It would be best if you could go through all the correct propositions commonly used with *inquire* with example sentences.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You **inquire of** someone.

> "Where do you live?", he **inquired of** Mike.

You **inquire about** something.

> He **inquired about** items for sale.

You use **inquire after** to ask about the health of (someone).

> He **inquired after** his parents.

You use **inquire for** to ask to see or speak to (someone).

> Mike was here **inquiring for** you.

You use **inquire into** to investigate or look into something.

> The police are inquiring into the causes of recent political events.

And, you could *inquire with* people, freedom, power, respect, eagerness, etc.

> "He will *inquire with* more earnestness, and decide with more impartiality."
>
> "We **inquire about**, and we **inquire with**; we inquire about various objects of inquiry, and we inquire with fellow inquirers"
>
> "And first we must **inquire with** respect to the moon, in what manner that motion blends relations or natures with the moon. But this we do not see prevail except in the monthly repairing of the moon, for the periodical course of six hours"

Ref. some definitions come from Oxford dictionary.

Answer (score 9):

*Enquire* (or *inquire*, which is less frequent in British English) may be used with a few prepositions.

enquire ***about*** with the meaning of "to ask somebody for some information" as in the example *I called the station to enquire about train times.*

enquire ***into*** with the meaning of "to officially investigate" as in *A committee will enquire into the allegations.*

enquire ***after*** somebody (formal) with the meaning of "to ask for information about somebody" (especially about their health or about what they are doing), as in *Auntie Jane called this afternoon and enquired after you."

P.S. all the examples are to be found [here](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/enquire), where you can also find an example of "enquire ***of***". I haven't found any example of the usage "*enquire* ***with***"

Answer (score 4):

The synonym of [inquire](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/inquire) is "to ask." This is why the most common Prepositions attached to it are "about," "into," "after," and "for."

"Inquire of" is indeed used with the specific meaning of directing the query to a person e.g. I'll inquire **of** my aunt...

But I don't think it's a good idea to substitute "with" there.

I suppose in another situation, such as inquiring together with or as a part of, "inquire **with**" can be employed.

If you believe the expression is "overly official" and "potentially archaic," I'd suggest not only changing the Preposition but practicing an altogether different word: "ask" instead.