# Can 'enquire' or 'inquire' be used without a preposition?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs

I referenced [Prepositions used with "inquire"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73856/prepositions-used-with-inquire/73860#73860). I can't pinpoint why, but I'm still wildered about "to enquire **of**". When can **of**  be omitted, but still retain the same meaning as "to enquire **of**"?  Are there any similarities or differences between 'to enquire' and "to enquire **of**" ?

For example, how can the following Notice to Counsel at the US Supreme Court be rewritten using only "to enquire", without any succeeding prepositions?

> "Counsel shall not inquire **of** the Chief Justice how much time remains."

Footnote: Reflecting American English, the foregoing quote above uses 'inquire', but I am guessing that here, it means the same as 'enquire'.

Comment: Please note that you are asking about _enquire_ in your question, but your quote mentions _inquire_. They are similar, but they are not the same verbs. I would, in case of your quote, use _enquire_ though.

Comment: It's not. One usually inquires of, about, if, into, after, etc. But unless *inquire(d)* is at the end of a sentence, it is not used without a preposition. *Inquire and enquire are not used with a direct object*; 'ask' is.

Comment: Are you asking if "Counsel shall not inquire the Chief Justice how much time remains" is grammatical?

Comment: @curiousdannii Yes, but moreover, why it's so?

Comment: @medica To what does "it's not" refer?

Answer (score 1):

@medica's comment is correct. "Enquire" or "inquire" are not used without a preposition:

> One usually inquires of, about, if, into, after, etc. But unless *inquire(d)* is at the end of a sentence, it is not used without a preposition. *Inquire and enquire are not used with a direct object*; 'ask' is.

Comment: To what does "it's not" refer? Please elucidate in your answer and not in comments?

Comment: @LePressentiment: I clarified the answer. Does that help?

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for the delay. Yes, but I clarified my OP. Would you please answer the reformatted questions?

Comment: I'm sorry, your newly formatted version is very hard to understand. Are you asking _why_ "inquire" is used differently than "act"?

Comment: Yes. I'll try to reformat, but please feel free to edit my OP.

Answer (score 0):

*Of* in this example is actually part of the direct object phrase "of the Chief Justice", specifying who the question is being directed to, rather than part of the verb *enquire/inquire* (which is essentially a synonym for *ask*).

Compare this use of *of* with *to* — in "I posed a question to the Chief Justice", *to* introduces the indirect object.

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the OP's question, which is *Can enquire/inquire be used without a preposition*?

Comment: Better after all the edits (mine and others')?